# Private Methods: Describing Errors

Tags: java, methods, private, bluej

I am working on the following assignment: An attempt to moveOn or backUp or to evaluate seesCD when it is illegal causes an abrupt System.exit(0) without explanation. The user would appreciate a tracing output in such cases. Revise these three methods to call a private method that explains the problem (with showMessageDialog) and then terminates.

I wrote the following code (please  scroll down the code):

```
   import java.util.*;
 import java.awt.*;
  import javax.swing.*;

  public class Vic extends Object
   {
  private static final String NONE = "0";
  /////////////////////////////////
  private String itsSequence = "";
  private int itsPos = 1;
          private final int itsID; // assigned by the constructor
  private void trace (String action)

    {

   System.out.println ("Vic# " + itsID + ": " + action

    + itsPos + "; sequence= " + itsSequence);

      } //======================



      public void backUp()

       {

       if (itsPos == 1)

      error("Could not backUp");

      itsPos--;

      trace ("backUp to slot ");

     } //======================



     public void moveOn()

     {

       if ( ! seesSlot())

       error("Could not moveOn");

        itsPos++;

        trace ("moveOn to slot ");

    } //======================



     public boolean seesSlot()

     {

    return itsPos < itsSequence.length();

    } //======================



    public boolean seesCD()

      {

    if ( ! seesSlot())

    error("Can't see CD, there is no slot");

 String s = itsSequence.substring (itsPos, itsPos + 1);

   return ! s.equals (NONE);

       } //======================



     private void error(String message)

      {

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: " + message);

      System.exit(0);

     }
     }
```

When I compile I receive the following error message:

"variable itsID might not have been initialized".
and this line is highlighted."public class Vic extends Object"

Comment: First, use an IDE that helps you with formatting, and don't insert blank lines everywhere. This code is a mess, and it makes it hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a `final` instance variable (which means that it has to be assigned a value exactly once during construction), but you don't have a constructor actually assigning it anywhere.

There's a comment that says *assigned by the constructor* on that field, but there's no explicit constructor. Perhaps you're supposed to write one, or it got removed at some point in the process of turning this code into an assignment.

Comment: Thank you.  That is a great answer, but what is the finalized version of what the code should be?  I don't know how to correct it.

Answer (score -1):

itsId isn't set anywhere, that explains your error.

But in general, this type of problem is solved with try and catch blocks and thrown errors. I'm sure you are about to learn about those.

Comment: `try`/`catch` and exceptions have nothing to do with this, which is a compile-time problem.

Comment: I'm talking about the assignment he has been given, not the error he is dealing with,